# Create an event / scheduling calendar with codeigniter and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, calendar

I'm trying to make an event / scheduling calendar using codeigniter and jquery. I need to be able to have multiple events on the same day, and I would like to make it as clean as possible.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of any good tutorials out there. All the ones I found don't let you add multiple events to 1 day, or have a really weird structure.

Thanks for the help!

Edit: 
Sorry about that, here are the ones I've found
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-file-uploading-and-image-manipulation/ (fairly basic and doesn't allow for multiple events on the same day)

http://www.okadadesign.no/blog/codeigniter/create-an-event-calendar-using-codeigniter-and-jquery/ Not sure how I feel about this one, or if it is easy to implement.

Comment: I was going to link a few that I found with a simple Google search.. but since you haven't listed which ones you've already looked at, I decided it's a futile effort.

Comment: Sorry about that, see my edit above (I added links)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you "can't" do it, you can modify any code and add extra events.  Are you saying the apps you found are too complex for you to utilize?  I would suggest going through the code and fiddling with them to find out.  Then posting questions when you need explanation.  That would be more useful, right now I am left wondering what a *'really weird structure'* is...

As for your own example:

- http://www.cecilieo.com/techblog/create-an-event-calendar-using-codeigniter-and-jquery/

It works and adds multiple events (I just added 2 for March 9th in the demo).

CodeIgniter allows for straight forward MVC (model view controller) structure (read the CodeIgniter userguide if you get stuck or confused).

Short of finding a very basic program I don't think you will find one that suits your need/learning curve (which is what I suspect the phrase "really weird structure" pertains to).

I would suggest simply trying the CodeIgniter flavour and tinkering with it until you get what you need, or you find that it truly does NOT meet your need.

Best case scenario you learn a bit more about programming through others code. Enjoy.

Comment: link--->404-->search site--->No results